# Androidplot error: Cannot resolve getGraphWidget and other method

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I'm currently developing an Android application for a university stage.
This application has to draw a plot with data which are coming from some pressure sensor, to draw this plot I'm using Androidplot library.

I'm following [this](http://androidplot.com/docs/a-dynamic-xy-plot/) example on Andrloidplot docs to create a dynamic XYPlot and I have imported androidplot-core:1.1.0 in the project dependencies.

In the code editor I'm getting the "Cannot resolve .... method" error everytime I call `getGraphWidget()`, `setRangeValueFormat()` and when I try to access `XYStepMode` fields.

I have searched for this issue on internet and on Androidplot docs but I haven't find anything usefull.
I think that this is produced by some import that I have missed, but I'm not figuring out what I've forgotten.

Someone has already dealed with this problem and solved it?

Here's a part of my class where I get the first error occurrence, it is on the last line:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.androidplot.Plot;
import com.androidplot.util.PixelUtils;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.*;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

/**
 * Created by marco on 07/09/16.
 */
public class GraphicChart extends Fragment {

    private XYPlot dynamicPlot;
    private MyPlotUpdater plotUpdater;
    SampleDynamicXYDatasource data;
    private Thread myThread;

    public GraphicChart(){}

    // redraws a plot whenever an update is received:
    private class MyPlotUpdater implements Observer {
        Plot plot;

        public MyPlotUpdater(Plot plot) {
            this.plot = plot;
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            plot.redraw();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graphic_chart_fragment, container, false);

        // get handles to our View defined in layout.xml:
        dynamicPlot = (XYPlot)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dynamic_plot);

        plotUpdater = new MyPlotUpdater(dynamicPlot);

        // only display whole numbers in domain labels
        dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));  //FIRST ERROR ON THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've resolved it, I've compared sources from the site I've linked and the one on gitHub.

Here changes I've made:

- lines

  // only display whole numbers in domain labels
      dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));

are now

```
// only display whole numbers in domain labels
        dynamicPlot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM).
                setFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
```

- `XYStepMode` is now only `StepMode`
- The call to `dynamicPlot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("###.#"));` is now done in this way

  `dynamicPlot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(`                    `XYGraphWidget.Edge.LEFT).setFormat(new DecimalFormat("###.#"));`